# Next.js form components wont allow to be edited once I give a value

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get a form working but when I set a state for the value of the input, it disables the text input (i just cannot type on the actual page).

I am using Next.js and its a part of a page.

```
  <Form.Field>
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <Form.Input placeholder='Product Name'
        name='pName'
        value={""}
        onChange={(e)=> setStateOfInput(e.target.value)}
    />
</Form.Field>
```

[Image of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdSbH.png)

---

Edit:

1. I added the line:
   onChange={(e)=> setStateOfInput(e.target.value)}
2. Also added this:

```html
var defaultProduct = { name: 'foo', email: '', submittedName: '', submittedEmail: '' }

   const [product, setProductState] = useState(defaultProduct);

   const setStateOfInput = (value) => {
            product.name = value
            setProductState(product)
      }
```

Comment: Components may be controlled or uncontrolled. You are mixing them. You must either provide a `value` **and** and `onChange` handler, or **neither**. Providing only a `value` will result in an unchangeable input.

Comment: I am looking to have it controlled. I want to be able to bind everything together.

Comment: In your edited post you are setting your state wrong, use it like this: setProductState({...product, name: value})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add onChange function to that input, where you will set new state, and value of input have to be state of that input f.e.

```
const [stateOfInput, setStateOfInput] = useState("");


<Form.Input placeholder='Product Name'
         name='pName'
         value={stateOfInput} // this is your state
         onChange={(e) => setStateOfInput(e.target.value)} // this function is called every time you type to this input, and then you will set new state
/>
```

Comment: How do I pass the value? e.val is undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure where `e.val` is coming from... It should be `e.target.value`.

Comment: I am trying to find a good guide. Can you share one please?

Comment: Its updating the value but still won't let me type

Comment: In your edited post you are setting your state wrong, use it like this: setProductState({...product, name: value})